# Getting Compile time error in java funciton body

Tags: java

I have created below code in java but getting error during compilation i have gone through with complete code but not able debug the problem

```
 package csaAutomation;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Date.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class GuiAutomation extends SeleneseTestCase {
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "url";
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGUI_Automation() throws Exception {
        String VAR_1="30000";

        public void GUI_Login_MR_SIT() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/CSAlogin");
        selenium.type("//input[@id=\"username\"]", "Administrator");
        selenium.type("//input[@id=\"password\"]", "Ari_123");
        selenium.click("//img[@src=\"/csaweb/resources/images/buttons/bf_login.gif\"]");
        System.out.println("-----------GUI Login Successful-----------");
        }

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Below is the error message :

```
  C:\CSA_GUI_Automation_0.4\src\csaAutomation\GuiAutomation.java:34: illegal start
     of expression
                    public void GUI_Login_MR_SIT();
                    ^
```

Please assist

Comment: You have shown one code and a compiler error complaining about completely different code.

Comment: please post the whole file source code. the error is outside this block

Comment: start with how to define a method in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Questions shows no comprehension of language fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared a method inside another method. I'm not sure of the intent of your code but I suspect it will work better if you have:

```
@Test
public void testGUI_Automation() throws Exception {
    String VAR_1="30000";
    GUI_Login_MR_SIT();
}

public void GUI_Login_MR_SIT() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/CSAlogin");
    selenium.type("//input[@id=\"username\"]", "Administrator");
    selenium.type("//input[@id=\"password\"]", "Ari_123");
    selenium.click("//img[@src=\"/csaweb/resources/images/buttons/bf_login.gif\"]");
    System.out.println("-----------GUI Login Successful-----------");
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry that was commented `    GUI_Login_MR_SIT();`

Comment: What was commented? Anyway, it is still wrong. You can't declare a method inside another method so, theoretically, my answer is still correct. Although, it is still unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks mikea!! it was my mistake...Problem is resloved now...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void testGUI_Automation() throws Exception {
    String VAR_1="30000";
    public void GUI_Login_MR_SIT();
```

You are trying to declare a method within a method body. This syntax:

1. is unsupported in Java;
2. generally has no apparent meaning which could be assigned to it.